# How can I improve the results of numerical integration using `NIntegrate`?

Tags: numerical-integration

```
Fn[x_, y_, z_, r_, 
   br_] = -1536 Im[(
    6 Cos[z] + 
     2 Cos[x] (3 + (-7 + 3 Cos[y]) Cos[z]))/(478 + 96 I br + 
      32 br^2 + 96 r - 64 I br r - 32 r^2 + 11 Cos[2 x] - 
      264 Cos[y] - 48 I br Cos[y] - 48 r Cos[y] + 11 Cos[2 y] - 
      336 Cos[z] + 144 Cos[y] Cos[z] + 
      12 Cos[x] (-22 - 4 I br - 4 r + 9 Cos[y] + 12 Cos[z]))^2];
```

I have the above function and I would like to perform numerical integration using `NIntegrate` with respect to `(x,y,z)` and then `r` with different upper limits scaled as `R` as follows

```
sg = ParallelTable[{R, 
     NIntegrate[
      Fn[x, y, z, r, 
       0.01], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {z, -\[Pi], \
\[Pi]}, {r, -5, R}, 
      Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]}, {R, -1, 1.5,
      0.05}] // AbsoluteTiming;
```

when I plot the results this is what I get

```
ListLinePlot[sg[[2]][[All, {2, 1}]], 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.01]}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 FrameLabel -> {"F(R)", "R"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", Black, 
   FontSize -> 16}, PlotRange -> {Full, Full}, ImageSize -> 300, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

while the expected form of the curve must be like this (**updated**)
[image]
So, how can I improve the numerical integration to obtain the desired results?

Comment: 1. Your reference data has no labels on the x-axis. 2. The integrand function has singularities.

Comment: @yarchik then what? I mean if it has singularities can't I use `NIntegrate` ?

Comment: If an integrand has singularities then the result is generally undefined. There are many cases when a well-defined value can be assigned to the integral. In 1D one would compute a Cauchy principal value. For multidimensional integrals this option is not operative and one needs to more closely analyze the singularities. You can specify them with `Exclusions` options (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#112801667)

Comment: The integrand does have singularities, but I don't think you ever encounter them in the given integration region. The denominator has both a real and imaginary component, and both `Reduce` and `FindInstance` tell me that there is not point in the integration region where both components vanish simultaneously, so we should be fine.

Comment: I tried some integration strategies for your previous question, and I got results similar to what you are expecting using the `AdaptiveMonteCarlo` method. I needed a huge number of points, though, and the accuracy was still pretty bad. The `LocalAdaptive` strategy also gave me results, but they disagreed with the Monte Carlo ones, and increasing `MinRecursion` something like 19 did not change anything.
For performance I you also could compile the function, that way you can get a speedup of another order of magnitude or two.

Comment: @Hausdorff, may you please share the code you used with `AdaptiveMonteCarlo` or `LocalAdaptive`? did you try to increase `Points `?

Comment: Yes, I increased the number of points to about `10^8` and I believe I got an accuracy of about `2`, which is not great. I don't think I saved my experiments, but I can write something up a little bit later.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, there do not seem to be any singularities in the integration region:

```
$Assumptions = And[-Pi<=x<=Pi,Pi<=y<=Pi,Pi<=z<=Pi,-5<=r<=2];

den = 478 + (96*I)*br + 32*br^2 + 96*r - (64*I)*br*r - 32*r^2 + 11*Cos[2*x] - 
      264*Cos[y] - (48*I)*br*Cos[y] - 48*r*Cos[y] + 11*Cos[2*y] - 336*Cos[z] + 
      144*Cos[y]*Cos[z] + 12*Cos[x]*(-22 - (4*I)*br - 4*r + 9*Cos[y] + 12*Cos[z]) /. {br->1/100};

denReIm = Through[{Re,Im}[den]] // FullSimplify;

Reduce[denReIm=={0,0} && $Assumptions, {x,y,z,r}]
FindInstance[denReIm=={0,0} && $Assumptions, {x,y,z,r}]
```

> ```
> False
> {}
> ```

By compiling `Fn`, you can further improve the evaluation time by a factor of about 100

```
FnCompiled = Compile[{{x,_Real},{y,_Real},{z,_Real},{r,_Real},{br,_Real}},Evaluate@Fn[x,y,z,r,br]]

Fn@@RandomReal[{-Pi,Pi},{5}] // RepeatedTiming
FnCompiled@@RandomReal[{-Pi,Pi},{5}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0000176, -0.00121113}
> {2.428*10^-6, -0.0177212}
> ```

The integration seems to converge to something sensible using the `AdaptiveMonteCarlo` method:

```
FvMC[v_,points_] := NIntegrate[FnCompiled[x,y,z,r,1/100],{r,-5,v},{x,-Pi,Pi},{y,-Pi,Pi},{z,-Pi,Pi},Method->{"AdaptiveMonteCarlo",MaxPoints->points}];

data7 = ParallelTable[{v,FvMC[v,10^7]}, {v, -1, 1.5, 5/36}];
data8 = ParallelTable[{v,FvMC[v,10^8]}, {v, -1, 1.5, 5/34}];

ListLinePlot[{
    MapAt[Around[#,14]&, data7, {All,2}],
    MapAt[Around[#,4.2]&, data8, {All,2}]
},IntervalMarkers->"Bands",PlotLegends -> {"10^7 Points","10^8 Points"}]
```

[image]

The error bands are based on the error estimates Mathematica gave me in the `NIntegrate::maxp` errors. For both runs, the average time per point appears to be around $1.4\times10^{-5}$ seconds, which is quite a bit slower than what it should be, but I suppose that could be attributed to overhead.

**Edit**

With Akku14's suggestions in the comments, i.e splitting up the integration region into subintervals, as well as using the symmetries $(x\leftrightarrow -x)$, $(y\leftrightarrow -y)$, $(z\leftrightarrow -z)$ of the integrand, we can further improve the result. The integration method `LocalAdaptive` now also seems to be able to give results in a reasonable time frame, so I'll also include it below.

We have to modify the integration functions to be

```
FvMC[vLow_,vHigh_,points_]:=
    8*NIntegrate[FnNumeric[x,y,z,r,1/100],{r,vLow,vHigh},{x,0,Pi},{y,0,Pi},{z,0,Pi},Method->{"AdaptiveMonteCarlo",MaxPoints->points}];

FvLA[vLow_,vHigh_,minRec_]:=
    8*NIntegrate[FnNumeric[x,y,z,r,1/100],{r,vLow,vHigh},{x,0,Pi},{y,0,Pi},{z,0,Pi},Method->"LocalAdaptive",MinRecursion->minRec,MaxRecursion->30];
```

In the `LocalAdaptive` case it is important to set `MinRecursion` to something larger than `3`. While `NIntegrate` does not throw an error for lower values, both the result and runtime make a jump, and tend to remain stable from there on out (in the following I am always using `MinRecursion->15`). My guess would be that there are features in the integrand that are too small for `NIntegrate` to notice for small values, but I am not really sure what is happening.

Performing the integrations in steps of `0.05` using the `LocalAdaptive` method, as well as `AdaptiveMonteCarlo` with both `10^7` and `10^8` points per interval, I get the following result:

[image]

The Monte Carlo results appears to converge to that of the `LocalAdaptive` strategy. The difference increases for larger values of `v`, but that is to be expected, as we are adding all the errors of the previous steps.

The plot is normalized to the point `{-1,0}`, since `AdaptiveMonteCarlo` and `LocalAdpative` appear to disagree on the value of the integral from `-5` or `-1`,

```
FvMC[-5,-1,10^8]
FvLA[-5,-1,20]
```

> ```
> NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 100000100 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained -5.3294 and 0.31752764339093775` for the integral and error estimates.
> -42.6352
> -52.8781
> ```

My guess would be that this is caused by features that are overlooked by `NIntegrate`, since the integrand is rather 'spikey'. Perhaps splitting up this integration region into smaller subintervals may help here as well.

Also note that even with the performance improvements the `LocalAdaptive` strategy is still very time consuming. The following graph shows the required time per interval of the results above:
[image: strong text]

Comment: this looks great! Note that `r` runs from `-5` (not `-2`) to `v`

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed it

Comment: Dear @Hausdorff, first, you can reduce time for integration by a factor of 8, if you regard `Fn[x, y, z, r] == Fn[-x, y, z, r] == Fn[x, -y, z, r] == 
 Fn[x, y, -z, r] == Fn[-x, -y, -z, r]` .  Second, do integration from r==-5 to r==-1 only once, store it and integrate then from -1 to -1+5/36, then from -1+5/36 to -1+2*5/36 and so on. Saves a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you, you are completely right. I'll try to work both of your points in later today

Answer (score 2):

Based on the detailed answer by @Hausdorff and the hints from @Akku14, I found that it is more efficient to transform the space integral into `ParallelSum` and then perform `NIntegrate` at each point with respect to `r`. Now the whole process  takes only `15 min` for all steps and with acceptable accuracy as shown in the attach Fig. Note that the max. value is about `60` (more close to the real one shown in the question) in the Fig. below while it was almost doubled, about `120` in the last result of @Hausdorff.
**updated**

```
    n = 101;
fxd = ParallelSum[(n/(2 \[Pi]))^-3 NIntegrate[
      8 Fn[x, y, z, r, 0.01], {r, -5, -1}, 
      Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], {x, \[Pi]/
     n, \[Pi], (2 \[Pi])/n}, {y, \[Pi]/n, \[Pi], (2 \[Pi])/
     n}, {z, \[Pi]/n, \[Pi], (2 \[Pi])/n}] // AbsoluteTiming;
SumInt = Table[
    fxd[[2]] + 
     ParallelSum[(n/(2 \[Pi]))^-3 NIntegrate[
        8 Fn[x, y, z, r, 0.01], {r, -1, R}, 
        Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], {x, \[Pi]/
       n, \[Pi], (2 \[Pi])/n}, {y, \[Pi]/n, \[Pi], (2 \[Pi])/
       n}, {z, \[Pi]/n, \[Pi], (2 \[Pi])/n}], {R, -1, 1.5, 0.05}] // 
   AbsoluteTiming;
Res = ParallelTable[{-1 + (j - 1) 0.05, SumInt[[2]][[j]]}, {j, 1, 
    50 + 1}];
ListLinePlot[{Res[[All, {1, 2}]]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Yours code dosen't give me a `Plot`?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, I added the part of the code to plot the results, check the updated version.

Comment: Thanks for updated version :)

Comment: Just to defend my honor, my plot has an offset since I defined the value at $-1$ to be zero, since `NIntegrate` was giving me inconsistent results for the integral from $-5$ to $-1$. Anyway, nice job :)

Comment: @Hausdorff, you did a grate job, thanks to your detailed answer I was able to figure out this method.